# Changing UITableView "back button" to a different color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I currently have a UITableView with static cells. Each of these cells are linked to separate view controllers via a push segue. The problem is that my navigational header is dark and therefore when I click on a table and go to the view controller that view controller's back button is difficult to see. How would I go about changing the back button to white instead of the default blue color. (preferably with storyboard)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change whole app tint color using `tintColor` property of your main window in AppDelegate.

Or you can change view controller's view `tintColor` `viewController.view.tintColor`.

Or you can change just navigation bar `tintColor`.

Or you can use this solution [iPhone Set Tint Color of Back Bar Button Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583603/iphone-set-tint-color-of-back-bar-button-item)

Comment: If I use this: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; in my app delegate, where in that file do I put that code?

Comment: @RyanE you can put it anywhere :) But before showing controller.
Usually, I add appearance customizations to some utils class. 
Maybe to your base view controller +load method. Or in AppDelegate.


UIAppearance is very powerfull thing, you can read about it here: http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/

Comment: just seemed to get it by changing the navigation bar tint color. Didn't seem to work earlier but I guess I must have had been doing something wrong. Thanks for the answer! :)