# How to set the tint of a single UIBarButtonItem in a navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

I have a `UINavigationBar` with a blue tint set by its appearance:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

During the navigation I have one `UIBarButtonItem`, connected to an outlet, that I want red! So naively, as I wished to keep all the other buttons of my bar blue, I tried that in the `viewWillAppear:` callback:

```
self.myOughtToBeRedButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

And guess what? It's still blue!!!

If someone has an idea... I need to tun it on both iOS 7 & iOS 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to change the UIBarButtonItem text color?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It's what the tintColor is supposed to do (at least it's what it does in Interface Builder)

Comment: Try moving that code to viewDidAppear:

Comment: Does not work either, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: Creating a custom bar button could be a solution to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583603/iphone-set-tint-color-of-back-bar-button-item

Comment: "And guess what? It's still blue" Because `self.myOughtToBeRedButton` is nil, perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not nil... But thanks for sharing... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `UIBarButtonItem`'s title text attributes in `viewDidLoad`:

```
actionButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

That single button will be red, and remaining items will use the navigation bar's `tintColor`. No custom button necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that only changes the text color. I need the tint to be changed, for instance when the button displays a glyph.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original UIBarButton's image. Change the type o render at Images.xcassets. Like this:

[image]